# SQLAlchemy automap MSSQL view with no primary key

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use SQLAlchemy automap to map an existing MSSQL view. I can successfully automap a table and perform queries against it but as soon as I target a view it fails. Here is some code of a couple of different attempts I have tried.

- Mapping a standard table works with the following:

  ```
  engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://username:password@serv.example.com/db?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server")
  metadata = MetaData()
  metadata.reflect(engine, only=['table_name'])
  Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
  Base.prepare()

  table = Base.classes.table_name
  ```
- Mapping a view with the following fails

  ```
  engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://username:password@serv.example.com/db?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server")
  metadata = MetaData()
  metadata.reflect(engine, only=['view_name'], views=True)
  Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
  Base.prepare()

  view = Base.classes.view_name
  ```

EDIT: I have now tried to create a class which maps a unique column as the primary key but I am still getting errors. Here is what I am trying.

```
Base.automap()

class view_name(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'view_name'
    some_id = Column('some_id', Integer, primary_key=True)

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://username:password@serv.example.com/db?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server")
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['view_name'], views=True)
Base.prepare()

view = Base.classes.view_name
```

And I am now getting the following error.

```
AttributeError: view_name
```

Comment: Does the view have a unique column that you could mark as the "primary key"?

Comment: Yes the view does have a couple of unique columns.

Comment: You'll have to [define a class explicitly](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#specifying-classes-explicitly) (just the "pk" columns) and instruct SQLA to [use suitable candidate columns as key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key).

Comment: I have amended my question with my latest attempts. Do you have any other pointers?

Comment: You could just use the class `view_name`. Automapping fills the rest in place, or at least it should.

Comment: Ilja, I have now managed to successfully reflect the view using your advice of just calling the `view_name` class, thanks! But I now have a second view that doesn't have a candidate for a primary key, what do you recommend for this? Can I add an arbitrary primary key id column?

Comment: You can, but preferrably said column should be unique. On the other hand core `Table`s can reflect tables and views without keys, so you could consider that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, Integer, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

Base = automap_base()

conn_str = '...'    
engine = create_engine(conn_str)
metadata = MetaData()
# you only need to define which column is the primary key. It can automap the rest of 
the columns.
viewname = Table('view_name',metadata, Column('some_id', Integer, 
primary_key=true), autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
Base.prepare()
view_name = Base.classes.view_name

session = Session(engine)

v1 = session.query(view_name).first()
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who still can get it working try this:

```
Table('view_name',Base.metadata, Column('some_id', Integer, 
primary_key=True), autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```